# ADF Copy into SQL table without creating source file

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a scenario to copy output of GET Metadata activity into a SQL table. Can I do this directly without using Databricks notebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of look up activity.

GetMetadata -> Lookup

And write insert SQL statement in Query, or use stored procedure.

[image]